# Memoir twocolumn showtrims

Tags: memoir, compilation-error

Can someone please confirm that this code does not run? I cannot seem to get the memoir class `showtrims` and `twocolumn` options to work at the same time. I just get a whole bunch of `! A <box> was supposed to be here. <to be read again>  \def  l.7 \end{document}` errors.

```
\documentclass[showtrims, twocolumn]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Additionally, if this is a bug, what is the proper way to go about and filing a bug report?

Comment: It yields no warning or error on my Ubuntu 20 with texlive 2021 using either pdflatex or xelatex.

Comment: I should add that I have pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) on mac. Tried compiling with pdflatex, xelatex, and lualatex (which is my default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error disappears using  `mparhack.sty  2021-05-02 v1.5`.

It fails with `mparhack.sty  2005/04/17 v1.4`.

[image: b]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\listfiles

\documentclass[showtrims, twocolumn]{memoir}

\settrimmedsize{0.75\stockheight}{0.75\stockwidth}{*}
\settypeblocksize{12cm}{14cm}{*}
\setlrmargins{1cm}**
\setulmargins{1cm}**
\setheadfoot{10pt}{10pt}
\setheaderspaces{10pt}**
\settrims{7.5em}{6.5em}
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```